# Live USB crashes when installing Wine

Tags: apt, wine, live-usb

I flashed `ubuntu-23.04-desktop-legacy-amd64.iso` (Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop with Legacy Installer) on to an 8GB USB drive. I booted into the live USB successfully.

In the live environment, I added `universe` repository and followed [the official method](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) to install `winehq-stable` aside from using `--no-install-recommends` instead of `--install-recommends` to save bandwidth and disk space.

All of this worked in past attempts. However, since several hours ago, when I am installing `winehq-stable`, the entire live environment would crash and hang. More specifically, when installing `winehq-stable` using `apt`, this happened at 74%. I retried after rebooting the live environment but still the same issue.

I have 16GB DDR4 RAM on my system so I don't think it is a problem with insufficient RAM (therefore disk space because live USB runs in RAM).

I have no clue why this is happening. Can anyone reproduce the same issue? Please help me to diagnose the issue.

P.S. the same occurs with another USB with Ventoy so this might not be a problem with the USB itself.

P.P.S. using `--install-recommends` instead does not fix the issue.